# How to install a handlebars helper with express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a node/express app which uses handlebars.

I'm trying to install this helper for handlebars. I installed it with npm, and the files are all there.

How do I use it on a page? I'm not sure where I need to include it. I tried in both the route and the app.js file.

```
error: Missing helper: "svg"
```

here's the route I want to use it with:

```
router.get('/app', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('app/index', { title: 'My App', layout: false });
});
```

This is the helper I want to install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helper-svg

Everything I find is just about creating your own helpers and not loading other peoples.

full error:

/home/ubuntu/workspace/views/project/index.hbs: Missing helper: "svg"

```
Error: /home/ubuntu/workspace/views/project/index.hbs: Missing helper: "svg"
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/helper-missing.js:19:13)
    at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:8:64)
    at main (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:173:32)
    at ret (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:176:12)
    at ret (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:525:21)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:63:19
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

app.js file: http://pastebin.com/Ge6NaDXc

Comment: You haven't provided any information about how you've added handlebars to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs');
hbs.registerHelper('svg', require('handlebars-helper-svg'));
```

Comment: That goes in app.js? I added that and it said i didn't have express-hbs, so I installed that. But I still get an error when I try to include it, I included the full message above.

Comment: If you don't have express-hbs, how are you using handlebars with express?

Comment: I believe it was just an option i set while installing express, I never set it up separately. I have a line with app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); Here's my entire app.js file: http://pastebin.com/Ge6NaDXc

Comment: Hey, I finally got it worked. The code you provided worked, I just also had to put things in the correct directory (which is the package folder, hopefully i can change that...). But thanks for your help.